Steampunk children's book where a clockwork world in a comic comes to life
I’m trying to remember a children’s book I read over ten years ago. The basic plot is that teenagers read a comic about a clockwork world which comes to life. Clockwork chimera start attacking and at some point the main protagonist ends up in the clockwork world and has to stop the villain which I’m sure is called Jack and is mechanical/clockwork himself. The villain Jack was very tall and I’m sure he had a descriptive word in his name like Clockwork Jack. Book chapters had names, some based off areas in the clockwork city like “the Rotunda”.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Were there any pictures in the book?  Do you remember the cover art?

Hello! Yes I believe the title was ‘slender’ and there was 2 books. One with  green cover. The other with a red with black silhouette shapes and writing. Both of which were one word title books

That sounds like Malice, by Chris Wooding (or the sequel, Havoc). The villain of the story is Tall Jake. Malice is the name of the other world he comes from, but also a comic book - the children end up inside the world of Malice, having to deal with the monsters found there. The book itself is a combination normal text and comic book pages, as below:


Cover colors also match OP's comments: http://books.google.com/books/content?id=ZOevEoMnXhsC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MaliceChrisWoodingBook1cover.jpg
